# What is the definite integral of...

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int^L_{-L} x \sin(\frac{\pi nx}{L})$$

I've seen something like this in Fourier theory, but I'm still not sure how to approach this integral. Wolfram Alpha gives me the answer, but no method. Integrate by parts? Substitution?

Comment: I suggest substitution: $$t=\frac{\pi n x}{L}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n=0,$ this is simple, so suppose not. Use the substitution $$u=\frac{n\pi}lx,$$ so that $$x=\frac{l}{n\pi}u,$$ and so $$\int_{-l}^lx\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}lx\right)\,dx=\frac{l^2}{n^2\pi^2}\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}u\sin u\,du,$$ then integrate by parts.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts letting $u = x, dv = \sin(ax) dx$, and so $du = dx, v = -\cos (ax)/a$ and you have

$$\int x \sin(ax) dx = \int u \cdot dv = uv - \int v \cdot du 
  = \frac{-x\cos(ax)}{a} + \frac{1}{a} \int \cos(ax) dx,$$

which should be much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have $p(x)f(x)$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial, and $f(x)$ is a function like $\sin(x)$ or $e^x$, such that differentiating doesn't increase its "order," integration by parts is always a good technique.  Differentiate the polynomial so it becomes "less complicated," and integrate the other function.

$$\int_{-L}^Lx\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\,dx$$
Let $u = x, dv=\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx$.  Then $du = dx$ and $v = \frac{-L}{n\pi}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$.
Thus,

$$\int_{-L}^Lx\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\,dx = \frac{-xL}{n\pi}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\Bigg|_{-L}^L - \int_{-L}^L\frac{-L}{n\pi}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, WolframAlpha *will* show you the steps to evaluate the *indefinite* integral associated with this definite integral.  It's then just a matter of plugging in the limits and subtracting.

Here are the steps returned by WolframAlpha via the Mathematica interface:

[image]